# cellForRowAtIndexPath called randomly and seems to leak memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app, I have the following `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. As it is to my understanding, this method should only be called to display the cells that are currently able to be displayed on the screen. As can be seen, I have a `NSLog()` function that should display the row that the `tableView` should display.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    PFObject *obj = [vars.feed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([obj.parseClassName isEqualToString:@"ProductCategory"]) {
        CategoryTableCell *categoryCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:categoryCellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

        ProductCategory *category = (ProductCategory*)obj;
        [categoryCell.nameLabel setText:category.name];
        [categoryCell.numItemsLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Items",[functions numberOfItemsInCategory:category]]];
        [categoryCell.banner setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:category.banner.getData]];

        return categoryCell;
    } else {
        ProductVerticalTableCell *productCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:productCellId forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [productCell customInit];

        ProductPrice *pp = (ProductPrice*)obj;
        productCell.pp = pp;
        productCell.banner.image = [UIImage imageWithData:pp.product.banner.getData];

        return productCell;
    }
}
```

The cell height is 175 and can only show 3 at a time on a iPhone 5. The results to be expected should be:

```
2014-09-16 13:55:06.331 Runn[38296:60b] 0
2014-09-16 13:55:06.333 Runn[38296:60b] 1
2014-09-16 13:55:06.335 Runn[38296:60b] 2
```

Indeed this is the only thing that shows up for a second in the logs, but then all of a sudden it goes through all the rows and logs out:

```
2014-09-16 13:55:06.331 Runn[38296:60b] 0
2014-09-16 13:55:06.333 Runn[38296:60b] 1
2014-09-16 13:55:06.335 Runn[38296:60b] 2
2014-09-16 13:55:08.389 Runn[38296:60b] 3
2014-09-16 13:55:08.393 Runn[38296:60b] 4
2014-09-16 13:55:08.395 Runn[38296:60b] 5
2014-09-16 13:55:08.396 Runn[38296:60b] 6
2014-09-16 13:55:08.397 Runn[38296:60b] 7
2014-09-16 13:55:08.399 Runn[38296:60b] 8
2014-09-16 13:55:08.400 Runn[38296:60b] 9
2014-09-16 13:55:08.401 Runn[38296:60b] 10
2014-09-16 13:55:08.402 Runn[38296:60b] 11
```

Then as I scroll, straight down to the bottom, without going back up at all, the full log looks like this:

```
2014-09-16 13:55:06.331 Runn[38296:60b] 0
2014-09-16 13:55:06.333 Runn[38296:60b] 1
2014-09-16 13:55:06.335 Runn[38296:60b] 2
2014-09-16 13:55:08.389 Runn[38296:60b] 3
2014-09-16 13:55:08.393 Runn[38296:60b] 4
2014-09-16 13:55:08.395 Runn[38296:60b] 5
2014-09-16 13:55:08.396 Runn[38296:60b] 6
2014-09-16 13:55:08.397 Runn[38296:60b] 7
2014-09-16 13:55:08.399 Runn[38296:60b] 8
2014-09-16 13:55:08.400 Runn[38296:60b] 9
2014-09-16 13:55:08.401 Runn[38296:60b] 10
2014-09-16 13:55:08.402 Runn[38296:60b] 11
2014-09-16 13:55:13.428 Runn[38296:60b] 3
2014-09-16 13:55:13.671 Runn[38296:60b] 4
2014-09-16 13:55:13.905 Runn[38296:60b] 5
2014-09-16 13:55:14.338 Runn[38296:60b] 6
2014-09-16 13:55:16.494 Runn[38296:60b] 1
2014-09-16 13:55:16.496 Runn[38296:60b] 2
2014-09-16 13:55:21.856 Runn[38296:60b] 7
2014-09-16 13:55:22.056 Runn[38296:60b] 8
2014-09-16 13:55:22.340 Runn[38296:60b] 9
2014-09-16 13:55:23.039 Runn[38296:60b] 10
2014-09-16 13:55:24.551 Runn[38296:60b] 4
2014-09-16 13:55:24.553 Runn[38296:60b] 5
2014-09-16 13:55:24.554 Runn[38296:60b] 6
```

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint inside the method to see who is calling it later? Can you post the stack trace? Can you post your other delegate/datasource methods? What is the `frame` (or layout constraints) on the table view?

Comment: I'm assuming you only have 1 `section` in your table? Also, what's going on with your log statements? Cell 0 has a timestamp *after* cells with higher indices.

Comment: @AaronBrager how do you tell who calls it with a breakpoint? Only methods I'm using is `numberofrowsinsection` and `heightforrowatindexpath`. There are no constraints. im using a plain tableview loaded from a xib file

@Stonz2 correct. and sorry about that i forgot to copy the first line of the log so i just did a quick copy and paste of a line. i fixed it